# Display time in hours and minutes (00:00) and round seconds to minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I want the time to always show 0's when less than 10 for example: if the task took 3 hours and 7 minutes and 33 seconds it would be displayed as 03:08

Right now I have the buttons disabled after they are clicked so that you cant restart the timer

Here is the JS code

```
let startTime;

const timer = typeof performance !== `undefined` && typeof performance.now === `function` ? performance : Date;
const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
const display = document.getElementById('display');

startButton.onclick = () => {
    console.debug('START')
    startTime = timer.now();
  startButton.disabled = "disabled";
};

stopButton.onclick = () => {
    console.debug('STOP')
  var totalSeconds = Math.round((timer.now() - startTime) / 1000);
  var totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  var totalHours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60 / 60);
  var displaySeconds = totalSeconds - totalMinutes * 60;
  var displayMinutes = totalMinutes - totalHours * 60;
  var strDisplayTime = 
    (totalHours > 0 ? (totalHours + '0:') : '') + 
    (displayMinutes > 0 || totalHours > 00 ?
        ((displayMinutes >= 10 ? '' : '0') + displayMinutes + ':') : '00:00:') +
    ((displaySeconds >= 10 ? '' : '0') + displaySeconds)  
    display.innerHTML = strDisplayTime;
  stopButton.disabled = "disabled";
};
```

Here is the HTML

```
<h1>
  <!-- This shows the heading of the entire checklist -->
  Master on Call Checklist
</h1>
<ul class="checklist ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ui-sortable" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="task">
  <li>
    <h2>
      <!-- This shows the heading of task that need to be constantly looked at -->
      <a href="#">
        Tasks that need to be constantly checked throughout the week
      </a>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <button type="button" id="start">Start Task</button>
  <p style="float:left;"></p>
  <!-- Heading to review cameras and adjest as needed -->
  <a>
    Review cameras and adjest as needed
   </a>
  <button type="button" id="stop">Finished Task</button>
  <div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `+((timer.now() - startTime) / 1000 > 30)` to `totalMinutes` and you need to calculate it mod `60`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99Lrrf3w/1/).

```
let startTime;

const timer = typeof performance !== `undefined` && typeof performance.now === `function` ? performance : Date;
const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
const display = document.getElementById('display');

startButton.onclick = () => {
    startTime = timer.now();
  startButton.disabled = "disabled";
};

stopButton.onclick = () => {
  var totalSeconds = Math.round((timer.now() - startTime) / 1000);
  var totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60 + +((timer.now() - startTime) / 1000 > 30));
  var totalHours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60 / 60);
  var displaySeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  var displayMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
  var strDisplayTime = 
    (totalHours > 0 ? (totalHours + '0:') : '') + 
    (displayMinutes > 0 || totalHours > 00 ?
        ((displayMinutes >= 10 ? '' : '0') + displayMinutes + ':') : '00:00:') +
    ((displaySeconds >= 10 ? '' : '0') + displaySeconds)  
    display.innerHTML = strDisplayTime;
  stopButton.disabled = "disabled";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var fixedDisplaySeconds = ( '0' + displaySeconds ).substr( -2 );
var fixedDisplayMinutes = ( '0' + displayMinutes ).substr( -2 );
var fixedStrDisplayTime = fixedDisplaySeconds + ':' + fixedDisplayMinutes;
```

Basically, always add `'0'` at the beginning and then get the last 2 characters - if time was `1`, then `'0' + 1 = '01'` - last 2 characters is `'01'`. Then if time is `11`, `'0' + 11 = '011'` - get the last 2 characters and you get `'11'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Date directly from your millisecond counter and use the `.getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()` methods to format it as `HH:MM`.

```js
// 3h07m33s in milliseconds
var ms = (3 * 3600 + 7 * 60 + 33) * 1000;

// create date (in the year 1970, which is OK)
var d = new Date(ms + 30000);

// format date as HH:MM
var strDisplayTime =
  ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
  ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);

console.log(strDisplayTime);
```

For browsers supporting it, you could also use `.toLocaleString()`. But it doesn't look like a very interesting option here.

```js
// 3h07m33s in milliseconds
var ms = (3 * 3600 + 7 * 60 + 33) * 1000;

// create date (in the year 1970, which is OK)
var d = new Date(ms + 30000);

// format date as HH:MM
var strDisplayTime = d.toLocaleString(
  'en-US',
  {
    timeZone: 'UTC',      // we've created a UTC Date, so we must display it as such
    hour12  : false,      // use 24-hour format
    hour    : '2-digit',  // display hours as two digits
    minute  : '2-digit'   // display minutes as two digits
  }
);

console.log(strDisplayTime);
```

Comment: Just for information: The second param of `toLocaleString` has IE11+ support and almost no mobile support (only Chrome 26+ supports it).

Comment: @metal03326 You're right (FireFox 29+ also supports it, though). I've added an alternate method.